# Kendo-Knockout: Maximum call stack size error when applying bindings on grid source data

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using RPNiemeyer kendo-knockout library. I have three view models that instantiate each other - `FranchiseDetailsViewModel` instantiates `LanguageListViewModel` which instantiates `LanguageDetailsViewModel`. The last viewmodel `LanguageDetailsViewModel` needs to have a reference to the parent `FranchiseDetailsViewModel` as its functionality depends on it.

html:

```
<div data-viewId="languageList" >
    <div id="languageList" data-bind="with: viewModel">
        <div id="languageListGrid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: languageViewModels, columns: [ 
                { 
                    field: 'Language', 
                    title: 'Language',
                    width: 50
                }

                ], 
            scrollable: false, sortable: true, pageable: false }" style="height: 380px">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

javascript

```
$(function () {

    var FranchiseDetailsViewModel = function () {
        var 
            self = this,
            initialize = function () {
                self.languagesInfoViewModel(new LanguageListViewModel(self));
                var parentViewModel = ({ viewModel: self.languagesInfoViewModel });
                var element = $('div[data-viewId="languageList"')[0];
                ko.applyBindings(parentViewModel, element);
            };

        FranchiseDetailsViewModel.prototype.languagesInfoViewModel = ko.observable();
        initialize();
    };

    var LanguageListViewModel = function (franchise) {
        var 
            self = this,
            initialize = function () {
                var languageViewModel = new LanguageDetailsViewModel(franchise);
                self.languageViewModels.push(languageViewModel);
            };
        LanguageListViewModel.prototype.languageViewModels = ko.observableArray([]);
        initialize();
    };

    var LanguageDetailsViewModel = function (franchise) {
        LanguageDetailsViewModel.prototype.Language = ko.observable("English");
       LanguageDetailsViewModel.prototype.franchise = franchise;
    };

    var initialize = new FranchiseDetailsViewModel();
});​
```

This reference to the parent view model causes some kind of a infinitive loop when the grid is binding to the source data. I am receiving `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. I believe the error is in the kendo knockout library when binding to the source of the grid because if I remove the grid there are no errors on the knockout binding to the div on this line:

```
ko.applyBindings(parentViewModel, element);
```

Is this the real reason for this error and how can I fix this? I cannot remove the reference to the parent view model so my hope is to fix the kendo-knockout behavior when binding to the source data. Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Zkyg/43/

Update per Niemeyer`s comment:

I have a div with some properties bound to `FranchiseDetailsViewModel`. One of these properties represents a checkbox - name it `isVisible`. I have another div with properties bound to `LanguageDetailsViewModel`. Some of these properties are visible only if the checkbox of the `FranchiseDetailsViewModel` is checked.  That is `franchise.isVisible` is true. This is the reason I need the franchise reference.

I am rather new to javascript and maybe I do not use the prototype property correctly. As I am instantiating my viewmodels with the `new` keyword I found that when assigning it to the prototype they become public and are visible in the markup so I can bind them. From your example I see that this.myProperty also makes the property public. I am not sure if there is a difference in my scenario.

I decided to use `this.myData.parent = parent;` as a solution to my problem. Thank You very much for your feedback.

Comment: What do you need to eventually do with `franchise` on the lowest view model?  If you just need to reference it in a handler, then you could just use the argument `franchise` directly in a handler. Otherwise, you could "hide" franchise, by making it a property of a function or observable (which is a function). Description here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/uSpZB/. I am not sure if I am on top of your use of prototype in these models as well.  Are you creating observables that you want to share between instances?

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I updated my post with update related to your commnet. Please post your solution so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment above:

One option is to  "hide" franchise, so that Knockout doesn't recursively try to unwrap it.  You can do this by making it a property of a function or observable (which is a function).

There are a few ways to do this:

```
var Child = function(parent) {

    //use parent directly from the argument passed to the constructor. available as part of the closure.
    this.myHandler = function() {
        parent.log();
    };        

    this.myData = ko.observable();

    //reference as a sub-observable. you can bind against myData.parent, but it will disappear when doing ko.toJS/ko.toJSON
    this.myData.parent = parent;


    //similar to sub-observable.  hide the actual value behind an empty function.  It will not be found when doing ko.toJS/ko.toJSON.
    this.parent = function() { };
    this.parent.value = parent;  
};
```

Example here: jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/uSpZB.

Normally you would not want to put observables on the prototype, as they will be shared by all instances.